# Need help in the shell script - gunzip and file command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell-script, gzip

This is on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a custom webkit based application where "browser" saves bunch of cache files. When triaging the problems, I have to inspect the cache. The cache directory holds many files of different types without any file extensions. Some of these files are compressed and some of them are not. Ultimate goal is to inspect the contents of text files such javascript and css.

I am trying to write a shell script that can "sense" that file is compressed file and expand the file. Facing two problems particularly

1. Checking the output of "file" command. This I got working with grep command checking status. Not sure if this is the best way to do.
2. gunzip does not like files without extension. How do I tell gzip to expand file without extension. Tried "-S" flag, but did not work I am stuck here.

If this (using grep and file commands) is not the best way, please suggest alternative way also.

In the following example, shell script should automatically expand 1077572923. Any extension or no extension will do on expanded file.

Output of ls -l command

```
-rw------- 1 <user> <user>  213 Apr 28 14:19 1011858703
-rw------- 1 <user> <user>  364 Apr 28 14:19 1040171657
-rw------- 1 <user> <user>  66K Apr 28 14:19 1077572923
```

And file * shows output like

```
1011858703: GIF image data, version 89a, 13 x 13
1040171657: GIF image data, version 89a, 22 x 19
1077572923: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
zgrep -e "the regexp you search" *
```

could be the answer.
zgrep does the uncompression for you, if necessary, leaving the files untouched and performs the grep.

Comment: Thank you, I tried zgrep, works great, but does not help me in actually seeing the file. I also need to look at the file also

Comment: May be you're zgreping on only one file, but if there are several of them, zgrep will prefix the lines with the name of the file (pretty much like grep). Isn't it what you want ?